# Couple of Things In Doubly Linked List Template

Tags: c++, templates, doubly-linked-list

I have a code of doubly Linked list and there are few lines of that code which idea is not clear . I request for experts comments on the lines which have comment in the following .Its long since I last time used C++ . There are just two line which i indicated are not understandable for me.

```
template <typename T>
class double_linked
{
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node* prev;
        node* next;
        node(T t, node* p, node* n) : data(t), prev(p), next(n) {}
    };
    node* head;
    node* tail;
public:
    double_linked() : head( NULL ), tail ( NULL ) {}
    template<int N>
    double_linked( T (&arr) [N]) : head( NULL ), tail ( NULL ) 
    {
        for( int i(0); i != N; ++i)
            push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    bool empty() const { return ( !head || !tail ); } // this doing? 
    operator bool() const { return !empty(); } // this doing? i know operators need in C++ but dont know the use of it here 
    void push_back(T);
    void push_front(T);
    T pop_back();
    T pop_front();

    ~double_linked()
    {
        while(head)
        {
            node* temp(head);
            head=head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I know its telling whether the list is empty or not , but again I wana know the detail of how its achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator bool() const` is a conversion operator. If an instance of `double_linked` is used in a context where a bool is required, this function will be called to do the conversion. (And will evaluate to `true` if the list is not empty in your case.)

The other function is a plain old function, which will return `true` if either `head` or `tail` is null.

For more about conversion operators, see: [How do conversion operators work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307876/how-do-conversion-operators-work-in-c)

Comment: same for array of instances ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. An array of `double_linked` won't have those methods/operators.

Comment: operator bool() const, a little more or easy explanation please ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first is a function to determine if the list is empty. In a doubly linked list, if you have at least one element then the `head` and `tail` pointers (which point to the start and the end of the list respectively) **must** point to a valid element. Therefore, you can test whether the list is empty by testing if both those pointers do not point to a valid element (i.e. are `null`). That is what the expression `!head || !tail` does - checks if either pointer is `null`, and if so the list is empty.

The `operator bool()` thing is a conversion operator. It basically means, whenever the list is cast to `bool`, that function is called and the result used as the value of the `bool`. The function returns whether the list is not empty, so an expression like `bool result = myList;` will make `result` be `true` if the list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is a predicate telling us if it is empty or not, it is checking if the pointers are 0 (null).

```
bool empty() const { return ( !head || !tail ); } // this doing?
```

This allows the user to treat a instantiation of the container as a boolean, which is true if it is not empty.

```
operator bool() const { return !empty(); } // this
```

Implemented a linked list is a good programming excercise but if you want to use a linked list in your actual code then you should really use std::list (in ).