# Conversion operator is not working for function parameter

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator

Why does this code not compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class vector_ref
{
public:
    vector_ref(T *pData, int pN) {Data = pData; N = pN;};
    T *Data;
    int N;
    vector_ref<T>& operator=(const std::vector<T> &v1)
    {
        for(int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++)
        {
            Data[ii] = v1[ii];
        }
        return *this;
    };
    operator std::vector<T>()
    {
        std::vector<T> v1(N);
        for(int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++)
        {
            v1[ii] = Data[ii];
        }
        return v1;
    };
};

template<class T>
void printVec(std::vector<T> v1)
{
    for(int ii = 0; ii < v1.size(); ii++)
    {
        std::cout << v1[ii] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    v.push_back(1.0);
    v.push_back(2.0);
    v.push_back(3.0);

    vector_ref<double> v_ref(&v[0],3);
    printVec(v_ref); // Compiler error

    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with `g++ 4.7.3` using the command: `g++ test.cpp`. The error message is:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:56:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘printVec(vector_ref<double>&)’
test.cpp:56:19: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:40:6: note: template<class T> void printVec(std::vector<T>)
test.cpp:40:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:56:19: note:   ‘vector_ref<double>’ is not derived from ‘std::vector<T>’
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308335/2018790) to a previous question seems to suggest that this should work.

Comment: I think you need `void printVec(T v)` instead of the `std::vector<T>` in the argument list. However, the operation inside that function will fail.

Comment: That gives the error: `error: ‘class vector_ref<double>’ has no member named ‘size’` in the function `printVec()`. I could assign `v1` to a `vector` inside the function but I would like not to do that.

Comment: Yes. That's what I've indirectly pointed out in the last comment. Your `vector_ref` doesn't have a member function called `size()`. You could write your own function and implement the functionality you want.

Comment: Doesn't `operator std::vector<T>&()` return a reference to a local variable?

Comment: In the code that I am working on I have a large number of functions similar to `printVec()`. I would prefer to leave them as is and have `vector_ref` converted to `std::vector` in the function call. If there is no way to do this I could then change the functions...it just isn't my first choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says:

```
test.cpp:56:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘printVec(vector_ref<double>&)’
```

Sure enough, that line is:

```
vector_ref<double> v_ref(&v[0],3);
printVec(v_ref); // Compiler error
```

Note that `v_ref` is a `vector_ref<double>`.  Now, the error message helpfully points out that there is a `printVec` function, but it's different:

```
test.cpp:56:19: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:40:6: note: template<class T> void printVec(std::vector<T>)
```

And if we go to line 40 and look at the printVec function, you will see:

```
template<class T>
void printVec(std::vector<T> v1)
```

So, here's what this means:

1. printVec takes a `std::vector<T>` as an argument.
2. You're calling it with a `vector_ref<double>` as an argument.
3. Those are completely different types, so it fails.

So that's what the error message means.

Now, I see that you're trying to make something that can be implicitly converted to a vector.  This gets messy because of the templates.  This approach works for wrapping non-template types, but has trouble with templates, and here's why:

When the compiler is trying to deal with `printVec(v_ref)`, it has to find the declaration for such a `printVec`.  It looks for something that takes `vector_ref<double>`, but doesn't find anything.  It does find a template function, so then it tries to see if the template function can be instantiated for this type.  The signature for `printVec` is that it takes `std::vector<T>`, and that doesn't match `vector_ref<double>`, so it doesn't match, and it moves on.  It really is as simple as "doesn't match, give up and move on".  It won't try to do any conversions on your type.

To solve this, you can add an explicit `.toVector()` as Sebastian suggests.  Or, it might work to explicitly instantiate the template method:

```
template<class T>
void printVec(std::vector<T> v1)
{
    for(int ii = 0; ii < v1.size(); ii++)
    {
        std::cout << v1[ii] << std::endl;
    }
}
template<> void printVec(std::vector<double> v1);  // explicit instantiation
```

That explicitly tells the compiler to instantiate the template method for `std::vector<double>`, and then when it's trying to find a match for `printVec(vector_ref<double>)`, it will see two options - a template method and an instantiated method.  The template method will fail as before, but it might realize that it can do an implicit conversion to use the instantiated method.  This *might* work, but I haven't tested it.

I'm not sure if that will work, and `.toVector()` is definitely cleaner.  But explicit template instantiation is a neat trick, and occasionally useful, so I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: The explicit instantiation won't work. But if you put it in the header next to the template, it *will* cause linker errors when you include the file from two different CUs.

Answer (score 1):

Your implicit conversion to vector& is unsafe and will do horrible things. Remove it. And turn up your compiler warnings, because the compiler should have screamed at you for it already.

The problem behind your compiler error is that argument deduction doesn't take conversions into account; it does strict pattern matching between the argument type and the parameter type pattern. And there is no match between `vector<T>` and `vector_ref<double>`.

There is no way you can make this line work. Either give `vector_ref` the full interface of a vector and make `printVec` a full template, or use an explicit cast or an explicit conversion function, e.g. `v_ref.to_vector()`.

Answer (score 1):

See Sebastian Redl & Tim answer for why it failed to compile

---

You can overload `()`: similar to `to_vector` function as suggested by Sebastian Redl

```
 std::vector<T> operator() ()
{
    std::vector<T> v1(N);
    for(int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++)
    {
        v1[ii] = Data[ii];
    }
    return v1;
}
```

then uses

`printVec(v_ref());`

See **[here](http://ideone.com/4BUJIa)**

Comment: If you're going to do that, you should simply create a named method, e.g. `to_vector()`.  That will be much cleaner and readable.  `Operator()` really shouldn't be used like this.

Comment: I agree with Tim. Using the function call operator for explicit type conversion is the kind of abuse that gave operator overloading a bad reputation in the first place.