# What is operator T* (where T is a template parameter ) in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class NullClass{
    public:
    template<class T>
        operator T*() const {return 0;}

};
```

I was reading Effective C++ and I came across this class, I implemented the class and it compiles. I have a few doubts over this:

1. It doesn't have a return type.
2. What is this operator.
3. and what it actually does.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307876/how-do-conversion-operators-work-in-c

Comment: It's a [used-defined conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). It allows instances of `NUllClass` to be implicitly converted to a pointer of any type.

Comment: Conversion or casting operator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's the type conversion operator. It defines an implicit conversion between an instance of the class and the specified type (here `T*`). Its implicit return type is of course the same.

Here a `NullClass` instance, when prompted to convert to any pointer type, will yield the implicit conversion from `0` to said type, i.e. the null pointer for that type.

On a side note, conversion operators can be made explicit :

```
template<class T>
explicit operator T*() const {return 0;}
```

This avoid implicit conversions (which can be a subtle source of bugs), but permits the usage of `static_cast`.

Comment: Not only can, but certainly also should be made explicit.

Comment: @Deduplicator we're precisely in the case where it should be implicit. You wouldn't want to keep `static_cast`ing `nullptr`, would you ? However I agree that implicit cast operators (and constructors) should be thought about twice.

Comment: Ah, you said "such conversion operators". My comment was more for the general case, though in this specific instance (a deficient re-implementation of `nullptr`), you are sure right that implicit is better. No rules without exceptions (even this rule has a few ;-)).

Comment: @Deduplicator I've dropped that "such" because I don't want to define it. Deciding of the explicitness of functions is a whole topic on its own, and outside the scope of the question, though you're right about using implicits sparsely :)

Comment: What is an "implicit cast"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Implicit cast" is a sloppy synonym for "coercion".

Comment: @FredOverflow: Very sloppy, since "cast" is a synonym for "explicit conversion".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed. It's like an *expensive bargain* or a *hornless unicorn* ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and what single word would you pedantic geniuses use to name all of converting, reinterpreting, casting and so on ? So these comments can be, like, productive or something.

Comment: @Quentin: Those are _conversions_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit does this apply to reinterpretation (punning) as well ?

Comment: @Quentin: Yes. `[expr.reinterpret.cast]` uses the term "convert" in basically every paragraph.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the information. I've edited away that "implicit cast" (which is actually a francicism).