# What does operator MyClass*() mean?

Tags: c++

I have the following class definition:

```
struct MyClass { 
   int id;
   operator MyClass* () { return this; }
};
```

I'm confused what the `operator MyClass* ()` line does in the code above. Any ideas?

Comment: It is a [conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060413/what-is-operator-t-where-t-is-a-template-parameter-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: thanks ,I will view the link URL.

Comment: @kinjia  "what the operator MyClass* () line does in the code above" - Nobody knows this except the author of the code.:)

Answer (score 7):

It's a type conversion operator. It allows an object of type `MyClass` to be implicitly converted to a pointer, without requiring the address-of operator to be applied.

Here's a small example to illustrate:

```
void foo(MyClass *pm) {
  // Use pm
}

int main() {
  MyClass m;
  foo(m); // Calls foo with m converted to its address by the operator
  foo(&m); // Explicitly obtains the address of m
}
```

As for *why* the conversion is defined, that's debatable. Frankly, I've never seen this in the wild, and I can't guess as to why it was defined.

Comment: Whoever wrote this code probably tried to emulate references :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I know, right? If only C++ had them :P

Answer (score 1):

It is a **user-defined conversion** which is allow implicit or explicit conversion from class type to another type.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) reference:

> **Syntax :**
>
> Conversion function is declared like a non-static member function or
>   member function template with no parameters, no explicit return type,
>   and with the name of the form:
>
> ```
> operator conversion-type-id   (1) 
>
> explicit operator conversion-type-id  (2) (since C++11)
> ```
>
> 1. Declares a user-defined conversion function that participates in all implicit and explicit conversions
> 2. Declares a user-defined conversion function that participates in direct-initialization and explicit conversions only.