# QtConcurrent blockingMappedReduced v.s MappedReduced

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

From my understanding `QtConcurrent::blockingMappedReduced` returns the final results, whereas `QtConcurrent::MappedReduced` returns a `QFuture` object, but in this example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-wordcount-main-cpp.html I saw code like this:

```
WordCount total = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(files, countWords, reduce);
```

`QtConcurrent::mappedReduced` function also returns the final results. Am I missing something? If this is wrong, what is the correct way to use the results returned by `QtConcurrent::mappedReduced`? And under what condition I should  `QtConcurrent::mappedReduced` instead of `QtConcurrent::blockingMappedReduced`? Please advise.

Comment: I guess that example code uses [the implicit conversion of QFuture to its underlying type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#operator-T) which would be the same as to call `WordCount total = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(files, countWords, reduce).result();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example `QFuture` object is returned directly to `WordCount` using QFuture object's [conversion operator to its template parameter type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#operator-T) which blocks and waits for the result to become available.

```
typedef QMap<QString, int> WordCount;
WordCount total = mappedReduced(files, countWords, reduce);
```

In practice, it's the same if you call blocking version of the function `blockingMappedReduced` or return `QFuture` object from asynchronous `mappedReduced` and block the returned QFuture object immediately. Note that calling `result()` or `resultAt(0)` also blocks.

```
WordCount total = blockingMappedReduced(files, countWords, reduce);

QFuture<WordCount> future = mappedReduced(files, countWords, reduce);
WordCount total = future.result();
```

If you want to interact with the QFuture object (pause, resume, check if results ready) then you can handle it asynchronously by calling `mappedReduced` and *not using the blocking functions*.

```
QFuture<WordCount> future = mappedReduced(files, countWords, reduce);
qDebug() << future.isResultReadyAt(0); // returns false
```

Comment: Can you explain what conversion operator a little bit more? I read the documentation and found no explanation there. @talamaki

Comment: You can define a member function of a class, called a conversion function, that converts from the type of its class to another specified type.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307876/how-do-conversion-operators-work-in-c/) for more details

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what does future.isResultReadyAt(0) mean? @talamaki