# Automatically convert one c++ type to another

Tags: c++, opencv, type-conversion

I am trying to make converting between a custom class and OpenCV easier.

[Converting constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) allow us to declare a class without the `explicit` keyword and construct from an alternate data type.

For example, we could declare two classes:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    std::vector<int32_t> data;

    Foo(int k) : data(k) {}
};

class FooProxy : public cv::Mat
{
public:
    FooProxy(const Foo & foo) :  cv::Mat(foo.data.size(), 1, CV_32SC1, (void*)foo.data.data()) {}
};
```

And then we can create a `FooProxy` by setting it equal and then then using any OpenCV function we want:

```
Foo myFoo(3);
myFoo.data = { 1,2,3 };

FooProxy fp = myFoo;
fp.setTo(1);
float myNorm = cv::norm(fp);

std::cout <<  "myFoo: " << myFoo.data.at(0) << ", " << myFoo.data.at(1) << ", " << myFoo.data.at(2) << "\n";
std::cout << "fp: " << fp.at<int32_t>(0) << ", " << fp.at<int32_t>(1) << ", " << fp.at<int32_t>(2) << "\n";
std::cout << "The Norm is: " << myNorm << "\n";
```

with output:

```
myFoo: 1, 1, 1
fp: 1, 1, 1
The Norm is: 1.73205
```

However, I would much rather write:

```
float myNorm = cv::norm(myFoo);
```

and have c++ automatically convert  `myFoo`. Is this possible?

This works:

```
 float myNorm2 = cv::norm(FooProxy(myFoo));
```

but not the simpler version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Then you should define a function in **namespace cv** like this:

```
namespace cv{
float norm(const Foo& foo){
    return cv::norm(FooProxy(foo));
}
}
```

Now you can call:

```
float res =  cv::norm(myFoo);
```

---

### The code:

```
//! 2018.01.17 09:42:16 CST

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

class Foo
{
    public:
        std::vector<int32_t> data;

        Foo(int k) : data(k) {}
};

class FooProxy : public cv::Mat
{
    public:
        FooProxy(const Foo & foo) :  cv::Mat(foo.data.size(), 1, CV_32SC1, (void*)foo.data.data()) {}
};

namespace cv {
float norm(const Foo& foo) {
    return cv::norm(FooProxy(foo));
}
}

int main() {
    Foo myFoo(3);
    myFoo.data = { 1,2,3 };

    FooProxy fp = myFoo;
    fp.setTo(1);
    float myNorm = cv::norm(fp);

    std::cout <<  "myFoo: " << myFoo.data.at(0) << ", " << myFoo.data.at(1) << ", " << myFoo.data.at(2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "fp: " << fp.at<int32_t>(0) << ", " << fp.at<int32_t>(1) << ", " << fp.at<int32_t>(2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "The Norm is: " << myNorm << "\n";


    float myNorm2 = cv::norm(FooProxy(myFoo));
    std::cout << "The Norm2 is:"<<myNorm2<<endl;

    float myNorm3 = cv::norm(myFoo);
    std::cout << "The Norm3 is:"<<myNorm2<<endl;
}
```

### The result:

```
myFoo: 1, 1, 1
fp: 1, 1, 1
The Norm is: 1.73205
The Norm2 is:1.73205
The Norm3 is:1.73205
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I was hoping to have it do the conversion since there are hundreds of OpenCV functions that would need such a conversation.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a [conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308335/2189130)

```
class Foo
{
  ...

  operator cv::Mat()
  {
    return cv::Mat(data.size(), 1, CV_32SC1, (void*)data.data());
  }
};
```

**Edit** `cv::norm` has the following overloads (notice no `cv::Mat`):

```
cv::norm(const Matx< _Tp, m, n > &M)
cv::norm(const Matx< _Tp, m, n > &M, int normType)
cv::norm(InputArray src1, int normType=NORM_L2, InputArray mask=noArray()) // this is the one we want
cv::norm(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, int normType=NORM_L2, InputArray mask=noArray())
cv::norm(const SparseMat &src, int normType)
```

A `cv::InputArray` can be constructed from a `cv::Mat`, however you're only allowed 1 user-defined conversion implicitly. So you'll actually need a conversion operator for `cv::InputArray` if you want `Foo` to work with `cv::norm`.

Comment: This is a great solution. Is there a way to not have the conversion operator be a member of class `Foo` so that I don't absolutely REQUIRE a dependency to OpenCV `cv::Mat` for ALL uses of `Foo`?

Comment: @Steve unfortunately no, the only way to do implicit conversions are with constructors and conversion operators

Comment: I try to run this code, but failed!  Error: no matching function for call to ‘norm(Foo&)’   `float myNorm3 = cv::norm(myFoo);`

Comment: I was afraid of that, I suspect it might not work because `cv::norm` doesn't have a signature for `cv::Mat`, it has overloads for `InputArray` but I think thats also a user-defined conversion... (can't have more than 1 implicitly)