# Whats the difference between these ways of overloading operator()?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

For me they look very similar. If you can direct somewhere where I can read about it I would appreciate it. Thanks!

```
operator int() const
  {   
    return value;
  }

  int operator()() const
  {
    return value;
  }
```

Comment: `operator int() const` is not an overload of `operator()`. It is the conversion operator `operator int` used when your type is being converted to `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do conversion operators work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307876/how-do-conversion-operators-work-in-c).

Comment: The name of the first function is "operator int", without a return type; it's a conversion function. The name of the second function is "operator()", with a return type of `int`, and it's the function-call "operator".

Comment: [User-defined conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) and [functional call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).