# How to write a add function chaining?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, chaining, function-call

I have questions on where to even start on this problem.
The problem requires the following.

```
// We want to create a function that will add numbers together,
// when called in succession.

add(1)(2); // == 3
```

I have never seen functions be used in such a way, and I am currently at a loss of where to start. Furthermore, I tried to do some research on parameter chaining, but this is all I could find.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-implement-method-chaining-in-c-3ec9f255972a

If you guys have any questions, I can edit my code or question. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> .... way and I am currently at a loss of where to start?

One way, is to start with an **anonymous (unnamed)  functor<sup>✱</sup>**, which has `operator()`, that returns the reference to the `this`, as follows:

```
struct {  // unnamed struct
    int result{ 0 };

    auto& operator()(const int val) noexcept
    {
        result += val;
        return *this;   // return the instance itself
    }
    // conversion operator, for converting struct to an int
    operator int() { return result; }

} add;  // instance of the unnamed struct


int main() 
{
    std::cout << add(1)(2); // prints:  3
}
```

[See a live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nM5n33esf)

---

<sup>✱</sup>Read more about the unnamed structs, functors and conversion operator here:

- [What are "anonymous structs" / "unnamed structs"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they)
- [What are C++ functors and their uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses)
- [How do conversion operators work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307876/how-do-conversion-operators-work-in-c)

Comment: This works perfectly and I think it has given me a great footing to understanding this problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to overload `operator()` and use a proxy object.

```
struct LhsAddProxy
{
   int lhs_;
   int operator()(int rhs) const { return lhs_ + rhs; }
};

LhsAddProxy add(int lhs) { return {lhs}; }
```